# Make Subset Class if needed only Few Properties from Class

Tags: wpf, oop

I have a class which has 100+ properties. I am using WPF/MVVM where i have to show all records of that class, but in my listing screen i need only 10 properties. To show so what should i do now make object of same class having 100+ fields or make a new with only 10 properties in it?

Comment: Why would you not just bind to 10 of the 100 properties? BTW. 100 properties seems a lot for one viewmodel. Are you (too) tightly coupling your viewmodel with the model?  Maybe some of those should be in separate classes. Use instances of these classes as properties in your current class.

Comment: @Andy point which i need to ask is if i use only 10 properties from that class and not needing rest of 90 and also don't assign value to them then will it take less space in memory?

Comment: If you had a viewmodel with just 10 properties compared to another viewmodel that had 90 more then the first viewmodel will use less memory.  This is often academic though.  If some of those properties were pictures or something uses a lot of memory and you were instantiating a big collection of these viewmodels then that's something to be concerned about. Otherwise, you may well be optimising for very little gain. If that increases the cost of writing your software and maintenance then that's a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It you want to show 10 out of those 100 properties just like they are, there is little reason to define a new type.

Of course those other 90 properties will be initialized with their default values for each instance of the class that you create so if you are intending to create a lot of instances, have a constrained memory limit or if the existing class does some fairly heavy initialization stuff, you should probably consider creating another type and use this one.

But in general it is perfectly fine to bind to a subset of the total number of public properties of a class without creating a new sub-type.